# Get rid of 'battery-low' popup after some delay?

Tags: notifications, battery-life

I'm using an Android phone (a Motorola Defy+ running CM9) with OsmAnd as a map solution mounted on my motorcycle (it just shows the map and a gpx-track as a driving hint).

It's not connected to a charger yet and I don't mind when it runs out of battery (I have spare ones).

However there's this "battery low" message popping up at 15% downwards. It covers a huge part of the map and stays there until you hit the OK button which does **not** work with gloves on and during the ride at all.

That remaining 15% still give >1h runtime which I want to enjoy withouth nagging popups!

Is there a way to hide it completely or get rid of it after some seconds automatically?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is hard-coded into the framework am afraid.

Look in `frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Power.java`

```
public static final int LOW_BATTERY_THRESHOLD = 10;
```

The alternative is to roll-your-own ROM to do this, there's a broadcast intent for battery low warnings (ACTION_BATTERY_LOW) but that's only for system signed apps AFAIK and cannot be intercepted.

The alternative is to listen for the ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED broadcast and perhaps using Tasker, just to mute the battery warning sound...

Comment: Anticipated that, sadly... Any idea how to automatically 'click' it away with tasker??? It's not the sound that annoys me but that it needs my attention and an action (click away) before I can see the map again (not possible with motorcycle gloves).

Comment: hmmmm....http://www.robotbriefs.com/tasker/2010/8/29/battery-low-profile.html

Comment: ah, a tasker profile. Not really good at tasker (although I have bought it once)... Thanks, looking at it atm... Maybe there's a way to click it away

Comment: I'm afraid t0mm13b is correct. Searching around, I found [Low Battery Sound Silencer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jmpdroids.lowbatterysoundsilencer.pro) in the playstore. In the app description you can read: *Note that the low battery window still will be shown, since it is not possible to eliminate it*. for an app like that, I'd assume the dev really did look for it.