# Can't find low battery threshold setting (Samsung Galaxy S3)

Tags: battery, samsung-galaxy-s-3

When the phone's battery reaches ~20%, I get the message to connect my charger on the lock screen. Is there a way to lower the threshold for the notification -- similar to the setting for a laptop?

For clarity, I want to change the settings so that the "Connect your charger" message appears when my battery is at 5%, instead of its current threshold, ~20%.

I should mention that I'm looking for a setting that's on the phone, without the need to modify back-end files. Also, I've actually gone through the whole settings section looking for the option and didn't find anything. Hopefully, I didn't overlook it.

Comment: See this [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27589/get-rid-of-battery-low-popup-after-some-delay/27593#27593) in respect to the battery threshold hardcoded within the Android system in itself.

Comment: I don't own a S3 but it's likely that you cant modify this threshold without flashing a custom ROM.

Comment: @t0mm13b Thanks for the link to that question. Unless somebody knows for sure that there's no setting on the S3, I think I have my answer. It's funny, I automatically assumed there would be a setting.

Comment: @user1037894 there is no setting for the battery threshold in any ROM, regardless :)

Comment: @t0mm13b Thanks for the information. If you make your comment an answer, I'll select it as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no setting available in any Android ROM that has the battery threshold setting.

From the previous [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27589/get-rid-of-battery-low-popup-after-some-delay/27593#27593) given, it is built in.

Only course of option is to roll your own Android build, with the hard-coded value adjusted, but, and is a big but indeed, it is not the recommended route to take, as the code behind Android to handle the battery mechanism varies from chip-set to chip-set and to each and their own manufacturer.

By adjusting it, there could be invariable damage to the battery as a result, since the threshold is specified, by "tweaking" it could affect the battery in the long run and possibly end up shortening the battery life also.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Galaxy S3 and changing the battery threshold had me stumped for a good while as I did manage to change it when I first got the phone.

Here's the answer to how to change the battery threshold on the Galaxy S3:

1. You do not need an app.
2. Simply wait until your GS3 gives you the low battery warning.
3. On your phone's homepage at the top, pull down the notification bar and tap once on the red low battery notification. This will take you to a power saving option page that has the battery threshold options.

**Note:** If you access the power saving options from the settings screen, you DO NOT get the battery threshold option??

I really hope this helps all those like me that just could not find out how to do this.

Comment: What version of Android are you using that has this?

Comment: I have a Samsung Note 2 and it does not seem to have this option.